# How do I look for a custom start tag using Jericho in Java?

Tags: java, jericho-html-parser

As the title says, I'm trying to match a non-standard StartTagType in the form of `<foo:bar ...>`

How would I do this with Jericho?

**Edit**:

I have created the follow custom StartTagType:

```
PrimoResultStartTagType primoSTT = new PrimoResultStartTagType("search", "<sear:DOC", ">", EndTagType.NORMAL, false, true, true);
```

...and:

```
class PrimoResultStartTagType extends StartTagType {

    protected PrimoResultStartTagType(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, EndTagType arg3, boolean arg4, boolean arg5, boolean arg6) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
    }

    @Override
    protected Tag constructTagAt(Source arg0, int arg1) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

However, when i do a `source.getAllElements(...)`, I get no matches.

Comment: It seems my start delimiter doesn't work even if i put something like "<div". I'm guessing the problem is in my second snippet.

Comment: What about the solution proposed below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help:

Example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>StartTagType (Jericho HTML Parser 3.1)</title>
</head>

<body>

<span>simple tag</span>

<test:name>custom tag</test:name>

</body>

</html>
```

And sample code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {

    URL url = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.html");
    Source source = new Source(url);
    List<Element> elementList = source.getAllElements("test:name");
    for (Element element : elementList) {
        System.out.println("Custom tag content: " + element.getContent().toString());
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
Custom tag content: custom tag
```